# How to find the two most common letters in a string?

Tags: c

The purpose of my code is to tell the user what is the most common letter and the second most common letter in the string and replace them with each other, but my code doesn't work properly. It finds the most common letters but doesn't replace them or print them properly. What is the problem?

Example input:

```
i love this game i do  do
```

Output (this line is printed):

```
Most common: i, 2nd most common: o
```

After that I expected this output, which is not printed:

```
o live thos game o di o di
```

Code:

```
int main()
{
    char array[MAX_LEN] = {0};
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int max = 0, secondMAX = 0, count = 0, save = 0;
    char saveForNow = ' ', highest = ' ', secondHighest = ' ';
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    fgets(array, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    array[strcspn(array, "\n")] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(array); ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(array); j++)
        {
            if(array[i] != ' ')
            {
                if(array[i] == array[j])
                {
                    count++;
                    saveForNow = array[i];
                }
            }
        }
        if(count > max)
        {
            max = count;
            highest = saveForNow;
        }
        else if((count < max) && (count > secondMAX))
        {
            secondMAX = count;
            secondHighest = saveForNow;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    //*I think the proplem is here
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == highest)
        {
            array[i] = secondHighest;
        }
        else if(array[i] == secondHighest);
        {
            array[i] = highest;
        }
    }
    printf("Most common: %c, ", highest);
    printf("2nd most common: %c\n", secondHighest);
    printf("Swapped:\n");
    printf("%s", array);
    //*I think the proplem is here
}
```

Comment: Hint: a string is an array that can be sorted

Comment: I gues you are just missing an `\n` at the end of your output string. Use `puts(array)`, it will do that for you.

Comment: The line `else if(array[i] == secondHighest);` ends with a semicolon, so this branch of the `if` statement does nothing. The next statement (`array[i] = highest;`) will be executed every time unconditionally. Also, shouldn't the inner loop start from `j=i+1` instead of `j=0`?

Comment: Declare an array `arr` of 26 integers. Traverse the string and for every alpha char `c` increment `arr [tolower (c) - 'a']`. Then traverse `arr` and find the two most common indexes. Finally swap the chars in the original strings.

Comment: Basic leetcode question. Use map to store occurrences to get O(N) time complexity.